# Async Renderer crash in Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am facing this crash. Has anyone faced something similar?

This occurs when there is a load more view which is in swift ui is loaded in a table view.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.